# git init Permission denied - /private/etc/apache2

Tags: git, apache, osx-yosemite, init

On OS X 10.10, I would like to use git with my apache in private/etc/apache2 directory. When I try to run `git init` I get `Permission denied`. What would a best practice be to add the appropriate permissions on this directory to enable git usage?

Comment: If it's for a conf file, maybe put your git repo somewhere more public, not totally public, then include that folder from your base Apache conf folder

Comment: @NathanGross Were you able to resolve this? If yes, don't forget to accept an answer below :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Permission denied is generally a file permission issue, where git doesn't have permissions to write.

One option is to run your `git init` etc with `sudo`, i.e., as `sudo git init` (though this is not recommended)

You could also create a new user and a new group, add your web server user to that group and initiate `git init` with this user. Another alternative is to add yourself to the apache group using `usermod`

Comment: While I believe your latter answer adequately solves my original question, I am thinking I'll end up going in a slightly different direction. Inspired by _Using Git and Github to Manage Your Dotfiles_ (http://blog.smalleycreative.com/tutorials/using-git-and-github-to-manage-your-dotfiles/), I think I'll simply move my properly configured httpd.conf file to a "apache-config" directory (in my home directory) and symlink it back to where it needs to go. I'll then init git on that "apache-config" dir.

I'll be interested to hear if you have thoughts regarding this approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As it is about to `Permission Denied` and **@mu** also mentioned about to use the `sudo` command,

Give the permission of the folder to the `user` by the following command -

`$ chmod u+x /private/etc/apache2`

Comment: After using this command, I still get 'Permission denied' when running git init.